# Hash-based navigation with puppeteer

Tags: mocha.js, puppeteer

I am trying to navigate to the url which contains `#` in the url which is returning `Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded`

```
it('should go to new link', async function(){
    await page.goto('https://example.com/#/abc', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
    await page.waitForNavigation()
    await page.waitFor(15000);
})
```

Original code expects a path to a tag having value as `#/abc`

```
    await page.waitForSelector('a tag selector')
    await page.click('a tag selector')
    await page.waitForNavigation()
    await page.waitFor(5000);
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'abc.png' })
```

Running the test file with command `mocha --timeout 75000`

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "karma": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "puppeteer": "^0.12.0",
  "requirejs": "^2.3.5"

}
```

Updated the code to

```
await page.goto('https://example.com/#/abc', {waitUntil: 'load'})
await page.waitForSelector('selector on desired page');
await page.waitFor(5000);
await page.screenshot({ path: 'abc.png' })
```

and added `headless: false`, I can see it does go to the page wait for some amount of time but still throw the error `Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to listen to history.pushstate with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900248/how-to-listen-to-history-pushstate-with-puppeteer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`goto` automatically waits for navigation. Your `waitForNavigation` is expecting it to make another navigation request. You also don't need to wait for 25 seconds to make this right.

However for such ajax site, IMO, you should wait for some selector that loads only when the page is completely loaded.

You can also pass a timeout parameter to increase the timeout and see if that works.

The following is good enough.

```
it('should go to new link', async function(){
    await page.goto('https://example.com/#/abc', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 60000 })
    await page.waitFor('#SomeSelectorThatWeWaitFor')
})
```

The best way to debug this is to see the behaviour of target page carefully.

Comment: You are right. My original code is `await page.waitForSelector('path_to_A_tag')
        await page.click('path_to_A_tag')
        await page.waitForNavigation()
        await page.waitFor(5000);
        await page.screenshot({ path: 'abc.png' })` and since A tag value has `#` in it. it doesn't goto to the desired link

Comment: Oh and what about headless: false, does it actually navigate?

Comment: I updated the code to `await page.goto('https://example.com/#/abc', {waitUntil: 'load'}); await page.waitForSelector('selector on the new page');` and added `headless: false`, it does load the page now but still run into `Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded` and doesn't take a screenshot.

Comment: Can you share the real url so I can test it out?