# How to get destination url of a dropdown item with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, puppeteer

I have this dropdown menu and I am trying to find the destination url for the "Edit" dropdown item.
Is there any way to get this url with puppeteer?

```html
<div _ngcontent-c34="" class="dropdown-menu" ngbdropdownmenu="" x-placement="bottom-right" style="top: 19px; left: -41px;">
<!---->
<i _ngcontent-c34="" class="dropdown-item ng-star-inserted" ngatranslatedtext="" tabindex="0">Edit</i>
<!---->
<i _ngcontent-c34="" class="dropdown-item ng-star-inserted" ngatranslatedtext="" tabindex="0">Delete</i>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What exactly do you mean with destination link?

Comment: A click on the "Edit" menu-item opens a new tab with a specific url. I want to find out what this url is.

Comment: What site is this and have you tried writing code so far?

Comment: What I don't see is, where this URL is supposed to be coming from - I can't see that in the markup you provided. Is it stored as an attribute on the tag?

Comment: @Raukaute yes, that is exactly my problem. I have no idea if the destination url is supposed to be stored somewhere on that page or if it could be hidden. 

I have no idea where or what to look for.

Comment: @Christian It still does not make sense to me. Where does the code in your example come from? Did you write it?

Comment: @Raukaute no I didn't write it. It is from a password-protected website that I would like to scrape.

Comment: You will probably have to make use of the waitForNavigation api. Something  like described in this post:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52900248/how-to-listen-to-history-pushstate-with-puppeteer).   To go another way, you’d have to find out how the event is handled on the page site. DevTools might help revealing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please bind & get the new page url.

```
  page.on('newpage', async (new_page) => {
        const url = new_page.url;
});
```

Comment: So it is only possible by visiting the new page?

Comment: Yes, you need to bind that event on the existing page where that dropdown will be displayed & once click on 'dropdown-item' then you have url inside the newPage page event of that new page.