# get post title after Infinite scroll finished

Tags: puppeteer

I manage to show all the post on a site where it has load_more button to go to the next page, but something is missing,

I got error of

```
e Error: Node is either not visible or not an HTMLElement
    at ElementHandle._clickablePoint (/Users/minghann/Documents/productnation_scraper/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:331:13)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Which doesn't happen if I don't load all the post. It's hard to debug because I don't know which post is missing what. Full code as below:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  devtools: true
});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto("https://example.net");

await page.waitForSelector(".load_more_btn");

const load_more_exist = !!(await page.$(".load_more_btn"));

while (load_more_exist > 0) {
  await page.click(".load_more_btn");
}

const posts = await page.$$(".post");

let result = [];
for (const post of posts) {
  result = [
    ...result,
    {
      title: await post.$eval(".post_title a", e => e.innerText)
    }
  ];
}

console.log(result);

browser.close();
```

Comment: Please be more specific: `getAllPostTitle function isn't working as expected` — how *is* it expected to work?

Comment: @Vaviloff updated my question with full code.

Comment: Thanks. But do you mean you load all the post or posts (plural)? How many times do you need to press load more button? Can you show the site?

Comment: @Vaviloff a lot, the site is http://productnation.co, the real selector is `jeg_post `

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways and best way is to combine the following two different ways.

## Look for Ajax

Wait for request instead. Whenever you click on Load More, it will do a simple ajax request to `?ajax-request=jnews`. We can use [.waitForRequest](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforrequesturlorpredicate-options) or [.waitForResponse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforresponseurlorpredicate-options) for this use case. Here is a working example,

```
await Promise.all([
 page.waitForRequest(response => response.url().includes('?ajax-request=jnews') && response.status() === 200), 
 page.click(".load_more_btn")
])
```

## Clean DOM and wait for new Element

Refer to these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50938956/6161265) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52886019/6161265).

Basically you can remove the dom elements that you collected, so next time you collect more data, there won't be any duplicates.

So, once you remove all current elements like `document.querySelectorAll('.jeg_post')`, you can simply do another `page.waitFor('.jeg_post')` later if you need.